# Fabricjs: cropping image with angle attribute

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, angle, rect

I crop an image through object method **toDataURL** (not canvas) with params such as left, top, width and height. It works great, but i don't 
know what should i do when an angle attribute of image doesn't equal 0?
I tried to call **setAngle=0** -> **setCoords()** -> **toDataURL()** restore **angle** <-- it works but not so well and i think this workflow is't good.

[image]

```
cropImage: ->
  sLeft = @glob.data.selectArea.left
  sTop = @glob.data.selectArea.top
  sAngle = @glob.data.selectArea.angle

  @glob.data.selected.setAngle(0)
  @glob.data.selected.setCoords()
  @glob.data.cropPicture.setAngle(0)
  @glob.data.cropPicture.setCoords()

  cropParams = {
    width:  @glob.data.selectArea.getWidth()
    height: @glob.data.selectArea.getHeight()
    left:   @glob.data.selectArea.getLeft() - @glob.data.cropPicture.getLeft()
    top:    @glob.data.selectArea.getTop() - @glob.data.cropPicture.getTop()
  }
  ...
  croppedDataUrl = @glob.data.cropPicture.toDataURL(cropParams)
  fabric.Image.fromURL(croppedDataUrl, (img) =>
    img.left = sLeft
    img.top = sTop
    img.angle = sAngle
    @glob.data.canvas.add(img)
  ...
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I wanted to crop an image at an angle and create a new object based on cropped.  I decided it through clipTo()

Answer (score 0):

**My solution:**

[image]

```
cropImage: ->
    # origin image
    originWidth  = @glob.cropPicture.getWidth()
    originHeight = @glob.cropPicture.getHeight()
    originLeft   = @glob.cropPicture.left
    originTop    = @glob.cropPicture.top

    # coordinates of the center of origin image
    ctxLeft = - originWidth / 2 + @glob.cropPicture.strokeWidth
    ctxTop = - originHeight / 2 + @glob.cropPicture.strokeWidth

    # crop mask
    width  = @glob.selectArea.getWidth()
    height = @glob.selectArea.getHeight()
    angle  = @glob.selectArea.getAngle()
    left   = @glob.selectArea.left
    top    = @glob.selectArea.top

    cropLeft = left - originLeft
    cropTop = top - originTop

    @glob.cropPicture.clipTo = (ctx) =>
      ctx.save()
      ctx.translate(ctxLeft, ctxTop)
      ctx.rect(cropLeft, cropTop, width, height)
      ctx.restore()

    @glob.cropPicture.angle = 0
    @glob.cropPicture.setCoords()
    cropData = @glob.cropPicture.toDataURL()
    @glob.cropPicture.angle = angle
    @glob.cropPicture.setCoords()

    fabric.Image.fromURL(cropData, (img1) =>
      params = {
        width: width
        height: height
        left: cropLeft
        top: cropTop
      }
      fabric.Image.fromURL(img1.toDataURL(params), (img2) =>
        @glob.canvas.add img2
      )
    )

    @glob.canvas.renderAll()
```

Comment: In your solution, quality of the image is very poor due to toDataUrl(). Is there any alternate solution where quality retains (same as original image) and work same as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Fabric.js Practice</title>
    <style>
        #crop {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    <button id="crop">Crop</button>
    <button id="startCrop" style="border: 1px solid #000000">Mark Crop Area</button>
    <br />
    <canvas style="visibility: hidden" id="canvas_crop"></canvas>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@5.3.0/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let currentImage;
        const canvas = initCnvas();
        canvas.preserveObjectStacking = true;

        addImage(canvas);
        createMaskForCrop(canvas);
        crop(canvas);

        function initCnvas() {
            return new fabric.Canvas("c", {
                width: 1200,
                height: 600,
                strokeWidth: 5,
                stroke: "rgba(100,200,200,0.5)",
            });
        }

        function addImage(canvas) {
            fabric.Image.fromURL('https://via.placeholder.com/400', (img) => {
                canvas.add(img);
                canvas.centerObject(img);
                canvas.setActiveObject(img);
                currentImage = img;
                canvas.renderAll();
            }, { crossOrigin: 'anonymous' })
        }

        function createMaskForCrop(canvas) {
            document.querySelector("#startCrop").addEventListener("click", function () {
                addSelectionRect();
                canvas.setActiveObject(selectionRect);
                canvas.renderAll();
                document.querySelector("#crop").style.display = "block";
            });
        }

        function addSelectionRect() {
            selectionRect = new fabric.Rect({
                left: currentImage.left,
                top: currentImage.top,
                width: currentImage.width,
                height: currentImage.height,
                fill: 'rgb(178, 178, 178, 0.4)',
                transparentCorners: false,
                cornerColor: 'rgb(178, 178, 178, 0.8)',
                strokeWidth: 1,
                cornerStrokeColor: 'black',
                borderColor: 'black',
                borderDashArray: [5, 5],
                cornerStyle: 'circle',
                cornerSize: 8,
                fillRule: 'Croping',
                lockMovementX: true,
                lockMovementY: true,
                scaleX: currentImage.scaleX,
                scaleY: currentImage.scaleY,
                angle: currentImage.angle
            });
            canvas.add(selectionRect);
        }

        function crop(canvas) {
            document.querySelector("#crop").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                document.querySelector("button#crop").style.display = "none";

                let angle = currentImage.angle;
                const group = new fabric.Group([currentImage, selectionRect]);
                group.rotate(360 - angle);
                group.ungroupOnCanvas();
                canvas.renderAll();
                let cropX = (selectionRect.left - currentImage.left)/currentImage.scaleX;
                let cropY = (selectionRect.top - currentImage.top)/currentImage.scaleY;
                let cropWidth = selectionRect.getScaledWidth()/currentImage.scaleX;
                let cropHeight = selectionRect.getScaledHeight()/currentImage.scaleY;

                currentImage.set({
                    top: currentImage.top + cropY * currentImage.scaleY,
                    left: currentImage.left + cropX * currentImage.scaleX,
                    cropX: cropX,
                    cropY: cropY,
                    width: cropWidth,
                    height: cropHeight
                });
                canvas.remove(selectionRect);
                canvas.remove(group);
                canvas.setActiveObject(currentImage);
                currentImage.rotate(angle);
                canvas.renderAll();
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[crop image using fabric js included image angle](https://jsfiddle.net/kartiksharma/u2nvom3y/)

1. click on mark crop area button.
2. moving/scaling a crop area rectangle.
3. click on crop button.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).